# How can I get the dataframe rows that differ in terms of unique class membership (on a column) compared to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

There are two dataframes (A and B) with the same column schema and the same number of rows and both are indexed by row number. One of the columns denotes class membership as an integer. I would like to efficiently get the rows from A that differ (relative to B) in terms of unique class membership on this column.

Example (Rownumber is the index, not a column):

```
A
Rownumber | Class
1         | 52
2         | 52
3         | 91
4         | 556
5         | 556

B
Rownumber | Class
1         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 2
4         | 3
5         | 3
```

Output:

```
1         | 52
2         | 52
3         | 91
```

Explanation: In A, the first two rows have a unique class membership (52), but in B, it's limited to the first row. Furthermore, one wrong membership of a group of rows immediately means that another set of rows is wrong: Row 3 in A has a unique membership (91), but it shares membership with row 2 in B.

A correct, but inefficient solution would be to iterate through unique classes in A, iteratively compare the unique classes' row indices with those in B and then add the group of rows to the output if there are more than one (or 0) unique class values for the corresponding group of rows in B. However, I'm looking for something that is quicker and shorter that likely uses groupby-calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `merge` and then `drop_duplicates`

```
df_c = df_a.merge(df_b, on='Rownumber')
# if row number is not a column
#df_c = df_a.join(df_b)

new_df = (df_c.drop_duplicates(df_c.columns[df_c.columns.str.contains('Class')],
                               keep=False)
              .drop(columns='Class_y')
              .rename(columns={'Class_x': 'Class'})
         )
print(new_df)

   Rownumber  Class
0          1     52
1          2     52
2          3     91
```

Answer (score 1):

Since they are of identical shape, you can concatenate the two hoizontally, and drop duplicates in the two class columns, then return only the original class.

```
b.columns = ['Rownumber','Class_b']

pd.concat([a,b['Class_b']], axis=1).drop_duplicates(subset=['Class','Class_b'],
                                                      keep=False)[['Rownumber','Class']]
```

Output

```
   Rownumber    Class
0          1      52
1          2      52
2          3      91
```